# Connect to the Docker Api without "--unix-socket" option in curl

Tags: docker, curl, netcat

I am currently trying to connect to the Docker API with the `/var/run/docker.sock` file.

```
curl -X GET --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://localhost/images/json
```

However, the curl version I use does not support `--unix-socket` and upgrading curl it is not an option. Is there any way to do the same using tools like `netcat`? Without any fancy stuff.

Comment: You might look at using a [Docker SDK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/), instead of trying to drive it using `curl`.  Or if you're in a shell context just run the `docker` command.  Is there a larger problem you're trying to solve that needs `curl` and not another solution?

Comment: I am in a shell / docker, but the `docker` package is not installed. That's why I was trying to use `curl` or even simpler, some sort of netcat. There must be a way to connect to the web API directly without going through the whole installation steps